# How to edit the correct phone number in my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWJQqj)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<label for="primary_phone">Primary Phone Number<span class="star">*</span></label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" class="_phone required-input"  value=""  maxlength="10">
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.invalid{
    border:1px solid red !important;
}
.valid{
    border:1px solid green !important;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
function phoneFormat(){
    $( "._phone" ).on('blur change', function() {
        text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
        var testt=$(this).val().match(text);

        if($(this).val()=='' || $(this).val().match(text) || $(this).val().length == 0)
        {
            $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        }
        else{

            $(this).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        }
        $(this).val(text);
    });
}

 $( "#primary_phone" ).blur(function() {
        phoneFormat();
    });
```

I put a script that arranges text format
for example, we can add this number :

```
1234567890
```

After calling script appears next form (what is right)

```
(123) 456-7890
```

The problem is when you want to edit my phone number ... if you want to delete the last two numbers because I put the following code  `maxlength="10"`

I want the user can not write more than 10 characters.
How do I fulfill both requirements.

If something is not explained well I'll do an edit to this post

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your link doesnt work, no code

Comment: sorry, the link works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all special characters when you focus in on the input box:

```
  $("#primary_phone").on("click", function() {
   var thisVal = $(this).val();

    var value = thisVal.replace(/[^\/\d]/g,'');
    $(this).val(value);


});
```

Now when you click out of the input box, your original function to format the number comes in to play :)

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/gto0qeyx/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would set a higher `maxlength` (say `15`) and bind the `input` to `keypress`.

Inside the event you can check the `keyCode` against a set of allowed ones and suppress the event (entry of the character) otherwise.

I would also suppress the entry of numbers if we already have `10` (with one exception: if the user selected (marked) a portion of the `input` and that `selection` contains numbers.

```
var alwaysAllowed = [32, 40, 41, 45]; // [" ","(",")","-"]

function keyCode(keyCode) {
    if (alwaysAllowed.indexOf(keyCode) !== -1) {
        return "allowed";
    } else if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
        // 0 - 9
        return "number";
    } else {
        // any other character
        return false;
    }
}

function countNumbers(text) {
    // return the number of characters [0-9] in the string "text"
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(text[i]) >= 0 && parseInt(text[i]) < 10) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

$primaryPhone.on("keypress", function () {
    var keyCodeEvaluation = keyCode(event.keyCode);
    if (keyCodeEvaluation === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (keyCodeEvaluation === "number") {
        var value = this.value,
            counter = countNumbers(value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd));
        // 
        if (counter === 0 && countNumbers(value) > 9) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

});
```

This would allow the user to edit (or write) the phonenumber with your format applied.

**MORE IMPORTANTLY**

You should **rewrite** your `phoneFormat()` function.

**Each execution adds** another **event listener**. The first time you change the `input` value it executes one time. Then **two** times, **three** times and so forth.

You should also **store** objects you use repeatedly in a variable, e.g. `$( this )` (creating the same `jQuery object` each time is a performance killer).

[Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/PZLxby) that should cover most of your use cases.